# Paste from Excel to WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, clipboard, paste

I have a DataGrid (called TheGrid) that I would like to implement copy and paste functionality on. The copy functionality works great but I don't know how to implement paste. Do I just need to get the data from the clipboard and parse myself?

The command bindings:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Copy" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" />
    <CommandBinding Command="Paste" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

The menu items:

```
<MenuItem Header="{x:Static culture:TextResource.CopyMenuItem}" Command="Copy"/>
<MenuItem Header="{x:Static culture:TextResource.PasteMenuItem}" Command="Paste"/>
```

The code behind for CommandBinding_Executed:

```
private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Command.Equals(ApplicationCommands.Copy))
    {
        // This works great, wow that was easy!
        ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, TheGrid);
    }
    else if (e.Command.Equals(ApplicationCommands.Paste))
    {
        //What do I do here? Is there an easy way to paste like there was for copy?
        // Or do I need to grab data using Clipboard.GetData and parse it myself?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not easy to do 
You should parse clipboard data with `ClipboardHelper`
take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118617/wpf-datagrid-pasting)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but what namespace is ClipboardHelper in? I can't compile and am getting the perty red squiggle :-/

Comment: look at the link in my answer

Comment: Ahh, the days when a link-only answer was good enough. Thanks though!