# DataGrid copy to clipboard - losing data

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, copy-paste

I wrote an app which is generating some report and after clicking right button it exports all data to Excel. When I personally use it I don't want to press button. I want to do: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and paste it to Excel.

The problem here is that after <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> it pastes 241 rows to Excel but in report there are 244 rows. It cuts 3 rows. I have no idea why, I tought that there is a limit but when I'm generating report with less rows it also cuts 2 rows. Any idea why is it happening ?

BTW: I didn't write any method for copying so I couldn't screw anything. I would be grateful if someone would help me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a web app or a windows app?

You could mimic the button press using a key combination (like ctrl+v) if it's a web app

Look here for more information:

http://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/

Comment: That's not what i need because i want to copy and paste it to different workbooks. I don't want to click button to make it faster instead of opening new excel file and copying it from this file.

Comment: Can you please tell us whether you are using a web app or a windows app?

Comment: IT's desktop APP wrote in WPF

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [WPF datagrid pasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118617/wpf-datagrid-pasting), it helped me when I was implementing similar functionality.