# How to extend xaml objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

If I extend an existing object, like a `DataGrid`:

```
    public class CustomDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
        static CustomDataGrid()
        {
            CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(
                typeof(CustomDataGrid),
                new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Paste,
                    new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(OnExecutedPaste),
                    new CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler(OnCanExecutePaste)));
        }

...
```

On the xaml side of things, if I try using a `<CustomDataGrid/>` I get something like, `CustomDataGrid is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project`.  So how do I actually use the extended class on the xaml side?

Comment: Note also that you usually shouldn't be subclassing UI controls, and putting a static constructor on it is just... odd.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Was just perusing the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118617/wpf-datagrid-pasting where they did something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the class by namespace. This involves adding a namespace declaration to the top of your Xaml file, and then using that namespace in your control element.

If we assume that your `CustomDataGrid` is in a namespace called `Rhubarb`, in the same assembly as the Xaml you're writing , you'd need to add this attribute to the root tag in your Xaml file (alongside the other `xmlns` attributes):

```
xmlns:rhubarb="clr-namespace:Rhubarb"
```

Then, where you declare your grid, use this element instead:

```
<rhubarb:CustomDataGrid />
```

If your cod is in a separate (referenced) assembly, you need to modify the namespace declaration thus:

```
xmlns:rhubarb="clr-namespace:Rhubarb;assembly=NameOfYourAssembly"
```

(Note that there's no `.dll` suffix on the assembly name.)

Comment: It's worth noting that dragging the control from the Toolbox onto the designer or XAML will do this for you.